# Sublime doesn't recognize extension

Tags: sublimetext, file-type

I've started having this problem recently.
Whatever document I open in sublime, it seems not to recognize it's filetype (php, html, blade, js etc):

[image]

I have to manually change the file-type in the bottom right-hand corner every time (here i've changed it php and all worked fine after that):

[image]

QUESTION: who can I make sublime detect file type as it did previously?

Comment: Try reminding Sublime of the settings that apply to each file extension type that is giving you trouble using the instructions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454555/how-do-i-set-sublime-text-to-auto-detect-a-file-type-after-setting-it-once/27456902#27456902 and let us know if that works or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default syntax to different filetype in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574502/set-default-syntax-to-different-filetype-in-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very easy. In the same right hand bottom corner, where I was changing the file-type, there is an option at the top "Open all with current extension as...". There you have to choose the filetype and sublime with remember it.
Here is the same question already answered:
[How do I set sublime text to auto detect a file type after setting it once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454555/how-do-i-set-sublime-text-to-auto-detect-a-file-type-after-setting-it-once/27456902#27456902)

Comment: This is what I am looking for since ages..! Thanks!